# PkcsInterop throws Dll not found on Linux

Tags: linux, pkcs#11, pkcs11interop

I am getting familiar with PKCS11 and using PKCSInterop. For now, I only want to check the tokens I created on my OS (arch linux) with softhsm2-util.

I installed PKCS11Interop through Nuget, which I installed previously on archlinux.

I get this error:

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.DllNotFoundException' en Pkcs11Interop.dll: 'Unable to load shared library 'libdl' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider using a tool like strace. If you're using glibc, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable

And I actually have libdl installed here

```
$: whereis libdl.so.2                                                                 
libdl.so.2: /usr/lib/libdl.so.2
```

What should I do here?

Answer (score 0):

I soft-linked the library to the required path.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.13/liblibdl.so
```

Shall I add an issue on Github?